# How to Collect Checked Values from Checkboxes Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to collect the values of the specific checkboxes and append them to another list.

Here is part of my HTML file.

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Pick the foods you like.</legend>

        <input id="tacos" type="checkbox" name="food" value="tacos">
        <label for="tacos">Tacos</label>

        <input id="crepes" type="checkbox" name="food" value="crepes">
        <label for="crepes">Crepes</label>

        <input id="dumplings" type="checkbox" name="food" value="dumplings">
        <label for="dumplings">Dumplings</label>

    </fieldset>
```

And Here is what I currently have with the javascript.

```
var $food = $('[name="food"]:checked');
$li.append($food);
```

First, I'm not getting all the food values I ticked. And second, I'm actually just appending the checkboxes, and the checkboxes get removed from the fieldset. I understand `$food` should be a list but I'm not too sure how to write this.

Answer (score 2):

Your current issue is that you are selecting the checkbox itself, as a whole. You only want to select the value of the label, and you don't want to move it but copy it elsewhere.

The code below uses jquery that runs after a click of a button with the `id` `#check`. The code cycles through each of the checkboxes with `name=food` that has been checked, and appends the `label` text linked to that checkbox to a list. **Update:** This list is then appended to the series of lists, with a header as requested.

I've included a line that you can uncomment if you want the list to reset between each check (otherwise you can have many versions of the same food in the list).

Let me know if you needed something else.
Hope it helps

```js
$("#check").click(function() {

  // Uncomment the line below if you want to reset the list
  // $("#lists .favourite-list").remove();

  // Create variable to store list of foods if selected
  tempList = ""

  // Check if any foods are selected
  $('[name="food"]:checked').each(function() {

    // Get the text value of the label
    // Should do this, rather than use 'for' value as it might differ
    checkLabel = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']").text();

    // Append a new list element
    tempList = tempList + "<li>" + checkLabel + "</li>";

  })

  // Check if at least one food has been added
  if (tempList != "") {

    // Add ul wrappers to list and header.
    tempList = "<div class='favourite-list'><p>Favourite Foods:</p><ul>" + tempList + "</ul></div>"

    // Append new list
    $("#lists").append(tempList);

  }

});
```

```css
#check {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Pick the foods you like.</legend>

  <input id="tacos" type="checkbox" name="food" value="tacos">
  <label for="tacos">Tacos</label>

  <input id="crepes" type="checkbox" name="food" value="crepes">
  <label for="crepes">Crepes</label>

  <input id="dumplings" type="checkbox" name="food" value="dumplings">
  <label for="dumplings">Dumplings</label>

</fieldset>

<button id="check">Add to list</button>

<div id="lists">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, how can I format it so for every submit, I have something for example like

-Favorite Foods: Taco, Dumpling
-Favorite Foods: Crepes, Taco, Dumpling 
-Favorite Foods: Crepe

Comment: Updated as requested.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to iterate over all the checked boxes

```
var $food = $('[name="food"]:checked');
$food.each(function () {
   $li.append(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a dynamic list of options based on the the selected elements and triggered on the click of the fieldset.

```js
$('fieldset').click(function(){
  var food = document.querySelectorAll('[name="food"]:checked');
  var foodStr = ''; 
  food.forEach(function(item){
    foodStr += '<li>' + item.value + '</li>';
  })
  $('#selectedItems').html(foodStr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
        <legend>Pick the foods you like.</legend>

        <input id="tacos" type="checkbox" name="food" value="tacos">
        <label for="tacos">Tacos</label>

        <input id="crepes" type="checkbox" name="food" value="crepes">
        <label for="crepes">Crepes</label>

        <input id="dumplings" type="checkbox" name="food" value="dumplings">
        <label for="dumplings">Dumplings</label>

    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <ul id="selectedItems"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get checked items with food name then append them to `<ul>`

```js
function submit(){
var $food = $('[name="food"]:checked');
var $ul= $('#li-id');
var li='';
$food.each(function () {
    li += '<li>' + this.value + '</li>';
});

 $ul.html(li);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
        <legend>Pick the foods you like.</legend>

        <input id="tacos" type="checkbox" name="food" value="tacos">
        <label for="tacos">Tacos</label>

        <input id="crepes" type="checkbox" name="food" value="crepes">
        <label for="crepes">Crepes</label>

        <input id="dumplings" type="checkbox" name="food" value="dumplings">
        <label for="dumplings">Dumplings</label>

    </fieldset>
    <ul id='li-id'>
    
    </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit()">submit</button>
```